# print media queries for dynamically generated elements with colors and backgrounds

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am tring to design a webpage where i need to give the ability to print for the user. so user can take the print of my web page with colors and images. I have tried with media queries for print like,

```
@media print{
div.div1
{
background-color:red !important;
}
}
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

its working fine for pages with static design i.e. colors and background-color for elements will know at the time of design. But i am in scenario where i am generating a list div elements with different colors and background-colors based on a certain condition. so i cant write print media queries for all divs because they are generating dynamically and i need to give the user to print option with colors. Or is there any other way to print page with colors without media query? How could i get rid of it please guide me.

Comment: Why can't you generate the media queries dynamically? That said, I'm not really sure what you want to do. When printed, your page is supposed to look different from what it looks on the screen?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible write media queries dynamically using jquery or razor. if so please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

CSS

```
@media print{
    div.red_print
    {
        background-color:red !important;                
    }
    div.green_print
    {
        background-color:green !important;
    }

}

@media screen{
    div.red_screen
    {
        background-color:red !important;
    }
    div.green_screen
    {
        background-color:green !important;
    }           
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="red_print green_screen">Hello World!</div>
```

This way, the background is red in print, green on screen. This is just an example: you have to write a class (for each media) for each colour.